# error defining a private class function in a cpp separate from header

Tags: c++, class

I really didn't know how to resume clear what I want to know, so the title might be a bit confusing. 
I have a class defined in a header, ex "CClass".
Inside this class a structure, ex :myStruct. 
In private area I have the signature of a function that returns a pointer of the myStruct type, ex: myStruct* (int a){};
I have a CPP file where I wrote the function definition.
I include the class at the beginning of the CPP but when I write the function definition I have the error: identifier "myStruct" not found.
I will insert the exact pieces of code down.

```
class CProgram{

struct var {
    int asc;
    int val;
    var*next;
};

  var *tr;

public:

  void init(std::string in);
  CProgram(std::string in);
  CProgram();
  ~CProgram();

private:
  void sub();
  var* search(var*h, int u);
};
```

next I insert the piece of the code from cpp:

```
#include "CProgram.h"
using namespace std;

var* CProgram::search(var*h, int u) {//here I have the error:identifier "var" is undefined 
while ((h->next != NULL) && (h->asc != u)) 
    h = h->next;

if (h->asc == u) return h;
else return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Because the type is `CProgram::var`.

Comment: The type is nested in `CProgram` so you should refer to it fully qualified: `CProgram::var`.

Answer (score 0):

`var` structure is nested within the `CProgram` class and thus is invisible in the source file, you have to fully qualify it as `CProgram::var` .
Then your function becomes:

```
CProgram::var* CProgram::search(var*h, int u) 
{
    while ((h->next != NULL) && (h->asc != u)) 
    h = h->next;

    if (h->asc == u) return h;
        else return NULL;
}
```

> The name of the nested class exists in the scope of the enclosing class.

See the reference on [nested class](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nested_types) for more details.